# Visual Studio 2013 - auto inserting "->" operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to make Visual Studio (2013) automatically replace *dot* with a " *->* ", when I press **.** after a pointer refering to object?

I mean the same as that useful feature (that I was used to ) in **Qt Creator**

Comment: Consider using fewer pointers.

Comment: That wouldn't be of much use when you declare the pointers with placeholder types though.

Comment: It would be impossible to do in full generality (e.g. when working with template types).

Comment: You will start cursing this added intelligence when you have pointers to pointers to objects that have both . and -> defined.  Happens a lot when you are playing with CORBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install VisualAssist add-on and you get that done automatically, along with other great features.

Comment: Is there any free equivalent? As I see it's really powerful tool, but also not the cheap one, and I don't really feel the need for it, as I'm still a beginner

Comment: I'm not aware of a free alternative.  If you use it professionally, the return in productivity pays for the software.   If you're a student, they have academic rates.   I personally paid for it for my studies.